# Angular.io How to render @ContentChildren elements?

Tags: angular

I have the following component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'seed-layout',
  ...
})
export class LayoutComponent implements OnInit {
  @ContentChildren(HeaderEntryComponent, { descendants: true }) 
     menuEntries: HeaderEntryComponent[];
}
```

I'd like to pass some components like this:

```
<seed-layout>
  <seed-header-entry>1</seed-header-entry>
  <seed-header-entry>2</seed-header-entry>
  <seed-header-entry>3</seed-header-entry>
</seed-layout>
```

menuEntries are getting populated, that's ok. But how then I'm supposed to render them inside LayoutComponent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use ng-content inside you LayoutComponent template in that place where they have to be rendered.

```
<ng-content></ngcontent>
```

As well u can use `select="seed-header-entry"` attribute of ng-content to specify contents in diff places and if this content are different.

Comment: it works! especially "select" attribute was useful. Thanks!